# getting googleMap template to display using dburles:google-maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor

This Meteor client code failed to show the map and not sure why. I am trying to show the google map on the screen for no avail. I ma not sure also where to use the google map api key. Any ideas? Thanks

```
.map-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```
import {google} from 'meteor/google-maps';

Meteor.startup(function () {
  GoogleMaps.load();
});


Template.gmap.helpers({
  mapOptions: function () {
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
      return {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8136, 144.9631),
        zoom: 8
      };
    }
  }
});

Template.gmap.onCreated(function () {
  console.log('gmap created'); // does not print
  GoogleMaps.ready('gmap', function (map) {
   console.log('Im ready!');  // does not print for sure
  });
});




<template name="gmap">
  <div class="map-container">
    <hr>
    {{> googleMap name="gmap" options=mapOptions}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'meteor/google-maps' and I don't understand why since it is added. Also Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys